# Angular: *ngFor with list index duplication error

Tags: angular

I have a list items and on click of individual items I'm trying to display inner lists enclosed by div like this

```
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li *ngFor="let guide of userGuideData; let i=index">
                <a (click)="selectedIndex=i">{{guide.title}}</a>
                <div *ngIf="selectedIndex === 0">
                    <ol>
                        <li *ngFor="let desc of guide.description">{{desc}}</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="selectedIndex === 1">
                    <ol>
                        <li *ngFor="let desc of guide.description">{{desc}}</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="selectedIndex === 2">
                        <ol>
                            <li *ngFor="let desc of guide.description">{{desc}}</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="selectedIndex === 3">
                        <span>{{selectedIndex}}-{{gpopo}}</span>
                        <ol>
                            <li *ngFor="let desc of guide.description">{{desc}}</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="selectedIndex === 4">
                        <ol>
                            <li *ngFor="let desc of guide.description">{{desc}}</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

I'm having separate div for individual list because I want to display each inner list in a different fashion. Problem I'm facing is, when I'm clicking parent list, all of the lists are getting expanded and clicked index value is getting applied to all the parent lists. I want only the clicked list to be expanded. What am I doing wrong? Please suggest. [Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rj4ZQSYdIq1TxR2xzMoY?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest not to stick to the index, because this approach will not scale over time and leads to duplicate code. My suggestion is to introduce new field inside each data object. You can do it with the loop on the client. And then collapse/expand based on that field. See the following updated code for **app.ts**:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <div>
        <ol>
            <li *ngFor="let guide of userGuideData; let i=index">
                <a (click)="toggleGuide(guide)">{{guide.title}}</a>
                <div *ngIf="guide.isExpanded">
                        <ol>
                            <li *ngFor="let desc of guide.description">{{desc}}</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  public userGuideData: any = [
    {
      title: 'Pre-requisities',
      description: ['Windows 10, i7/i5, 8GB/16GB RAM, HDD 300GB/500GB',
                    'Total size of the deployment : 1.75 GB. The system should atleast have 2GB free space'
    ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Installation Guide',
      description: ['Step 1:  Install Docker. a) For Windows: Follow the instructions from the link https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows and install the latest stable version of docker. b) For Mac: Follow the instructions from the link https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/#download-docker-for-mac and install the latest stable version of docker. Alternatively you can also use homebrew to install docker',
                    'Step 2: Once the docker installation is completed. Open the docker settings and go to advanced settings tab. On Windows increase the CPUs to 2 and Memory to 3GB. On Mac you can set it upto 4 CPUs and Memory of 6GB',
                    'Step 3: Unzip the deploymentpackage.zip file. Traverse to this folder on command line and execute the start.sh shell script. During the first time, setup will take time(minimum around 30 mins) to finish as we are downloading images to the local. For the subsequent runs it will take only few minutes to set up, depending on the speed of the system. Once the set up is done the console will display a message given below.',
                    'Step 4: Once the set up is successful. Open any browser and enter http://localhost:8080.  Make sure to free the 8080 port on your local system',
                    'Step 5: Login page appears. Enter the username ‘admin’ and password ‘admin’ and login to the tool.',
                    'Step 6: On launch you will be directed to the HomePage. Upload a zip file with the configurations, using the Upload configurations button. The input file should have a “.zip” extension only. Each device configuration in the zip file should end with a  “.txt” extension only.',
                    'Step 7: Once the upload is successful you will be directed to the Reports page. Initially the tables in the page will be empty. Click the Refresh button recursively to see the current status of the execution.  Once all the devices are processed, press the Download Reports button to download the report in an excel format. Please note that since this is a streaming architecture based application, there will not be any message rendered to signify the completion of the execution. This feature will be provided in the upcoming releases.',
                    'Step 8: For further uploads navigate to the Homepage and follow Steps 6 and 7',
                    'Step 9: For exiting the application, press cross button on the browser.',
                    'Step 10: For exiting the docker, execute the stop.sh shell script given in the deploymentpackage.zip. This will make sure the system is cleaned up(which mean that all data will erased)',
                    'Note: Please download the reports before exiting the docker',

    ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Known issues',
      description: ['Once the docker is stopped, the data will not be persisted. Download the reports and store them for future reference',
                    'The end of report generation will not be notified to the user. The latest status can be known by clicking the refresh button recursively',
                    'Configs with insufficient data are highlighted in the Fallout section of the report. Refer to the “fallout” sheet in the downloaded report for the same',
                    'This tool is not production ready. To make it production ready, tool needs to go through CSDL compliance process'
    ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Performance Statistics under lab conditions',
      description: ['First time application set up time: 27-30 mins',
                    'Total size of the deployment : 1.75 gb',
                    'Tool execution Time 100 configurations of a total 2.5MB takes around 3 mins. 500 configurations of a total 13MB takes around 15.30 mins. 1000 configurations of a total 16MB takes around 27 mins',
                    '7 valid configs shared by the NCEs have been modified to come up to the numbers of 100,500 and 1000 for testing. Note that this is just a ball park data'
    ]
    },
    {
      title: 'CDET details',
      description: ['Project: CSC.cacsp',
                    'Product: mig-sda-dna',
                    'Component: ui/backend/ic',
                    'Version: v0.5'
    ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Team alias',
      description: ['abc@abc.com']
    },
    {
      title: 'FAQ',
      description: ['Whom to contact for issues related to tool? Answer: Send all queries to team alias abc@abc.com',
                    'How to check if the processing of the upload is complete? Answer: Once the upload is successful you will be directed to the Reports page. Initially the tables in the page will be empty. Click the Refresh button recursively to see the current status of the execution. All valid configurations will be displayed in the Summary tab, the invalid configurations will be displayed in the  Fallout tab',
                    'How to do crash recovery ? Answer: Since this is an on prem docker based deliverable, there will be times when the application might crash if the system resources are not sufficient. In case you face such issues we recommend you to restart the application and/or increase the docker resources by following the Step 2 of installation guide section. If the issue still persists report the same',
                    'Can this tool be used for customer deliverables? Answer: A strict “NO”. The tool is not security compliant and should not be used for processing customer data. Future releases will be addressing this issue'
    ]
    }
  ]

  constructor() {
    this.userGuideData.forEach((element) => {
      element.isExpanded = false;
    }
  }

  toggleGuide(guide) {
    guide.isExpanded = !guide.isExpanded;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Working Plunker is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/VfnH4XCoqyxjo1zfJzUx?p=preview

Comment: Is it possible to expand all with a single click from a button?

Comment: Sure. See how they all set to false in the constructor? Setting them all to true will expand them all.

Answer (score 1):

Only `selectedIndex` will work for everyone. You need to be specific.
Update your code as below

```
<li *ngFor="let guide of userGuideData; let i=index">
                <a (click)="selectedIndex = i">{{guide.title}}</a>
                <div *ngIf="selectedIndex == i">
                        <ol>
                            <li *ngFor="let desc of guide.description">{{desc}}</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: This is working but why its not toggling, if I click on second, first list get hidden as guide.selectedIndex is changing